# Recursion and return values in python

Tags: python, recursion

```
a="003020600900305001001806400008102900700000008006708200002609500800203009005010300"
b=[]
def same_row(i,j): return (i/9 == j/9)
def same_col(i,j): return (i-j) % 9 == 0
def same_block(i,j): return (i/27 == j/27 and i%9/3 == j%9/3)
def r(a):
  i = a.find('0')
  if i == -1:
      b.append(a)
      return a

  excluded_numbers = set()
  for j in range(81):
    if same_row(i,j) or same_col(i,j) or same_block(i,j):
      excluded_numbers.add(a[j])

  for m in '123456789':
    if m not in excluded_numbers:
      return r(a[:i]+m+a[i+1:])


print r(a),b
```

This is a sudoku solver. It inputs a 81 size string with 0 and 1-9 numbers and returns a string without the 0s. The given example inputs a string `a` and it is supposed to return the result string. You can verify that the function returns a result by putting `exit(a)` instead of `return a` and `b.append(a)`

When trying to print the result returned by the recursive function `r` it returns nothing. Also despite of the fact that I fill the `b` table with `b.append(a)` it prints an empty table.

Comment: AFAIK python isn't the best language to try recursion, it can run out of stack very quickly.

Comment: How about an example of the desired output?

Comment: @JonClements I think he is trying to solve Sudoku and he wants to print the solved board.

Comment: the output i expect it to be a string: for example: "12343132..."

Comment: @thefourtheye indeed... with `0` being an unsolved/to be solved value... but nothing in the code, nor text of the question describes, how they're trying to output it...

Comment: @JonClements I don't know. The code looks like part of a puzzle and we have to complete it.

Comment: What _are_ you trying to do, because `i` is not initiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` the value of the recursive call to `r`

Comment: You're calling `r` within itself, but you haven't used `return` so the value from the recursive call is being thrown away.